# How do I read a segment of a file, defined by the number of characters to read, in C++?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have some problems reading specific data from a file. The file has 80 characters on the first and second line and an unknown number of characters on the third line. The following is my code:

```
int main(){
    ifstream myfile;
    char strings[80];
    myfile.open("test.txt");
    /*reads first line of file into strings*/
    cout << "Name: " << strings << endl;
    /*reads second line of file into strings*/
    cout << "Address: " << strings << endl;
    /*reads third line of file into strings*/
    cout << "Handphone: " << strings << endl;
}
```

How do i do the actions in the comments?

Comment: If you want to read lines, use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/). If you want to read some precise number of bytes, use [read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/).

Comment: and use `std::string` instead to handle the 3rd line.

Comment: Thousands of duplicates of this by now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char strings[80]` can only hold 79 characters. Make it `char strings[81]`. You can forget about the size altogether if you use `std::string`.

You can read lines with the [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) function.

```
#include <string>

std::string strings;

/*reads first line of file into strings*/
std::getline( myfile, strings );

/*reads second line of file into strings*/
std::getline( myfile, strings );

/*reads third line of file into strings*/
std::getline( myfile, strings );
```

The code above ignores the information that the first and second lines are 80 chars long (I'm assuming you're reading a line-based file format). You can add an additional check for that if it's important.

Comment: But when i display added cout<<strings<<endl;
It displayed nothing, what do i do next?

Comment: Perhaps the file was not found or the content is not valid. Check for errors using `if( !myfile ) cout << "File error" << endl;` after every operation, including `myfile.open`.

Comment: Ok, found the problem in the orginal code... My file path was wrong. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In your case it will be more appropriate to use string rather than char[].

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream myfile;
    //char strings[80];
    string strings;
    myfile.open("test.txt");

    /*reads first line of file into strings*/
    getline(myfile, strings);
    cout << "Name: " << strings << endl;
    /*reads second line of file into strings*/
    getline(myfile, strings);
    cout << "Address: " << strings << endl;
    /*reads third line of file into strings*/
    getline(myfile, strings);
    cout << "Handphone: " << strings << endl;
}
```